# Android Marshmallow - Why dangerous permission is granted without asking user

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My SMS App uses several dangerous permissions like **Send SMS, Read Contacts** etc and I am trying to test new permission system for android 6.0 But when I install it on Android 6.0 device, it has already granted those permissions without asking at run time. Why is this? I have uninstalled and installed it fresh too, but same result.

**Note**: I can see permission dialog at run time when app tries to access camera. But not for SMS, Location or Phone related permissions which are categorized as dangerous too.

Any clue why is this happening?

**Edit:** My targetSdkVersion is 23

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @CommonsWare `targetSdkVersion` is 23

Comment: and you are able to do some stuff with SMS? Sending, reading etc...? With which device you have checked it?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes, I can send and read SMS. I checked on an Android One QMobile A1 device - http://www.qmobile.com.pk/phone-androidone.html

Comment: I guess with original software, not custom ROM?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yes - original software. Updated couple of months ago to 6.0.1

Comment: can you post your app's build gradle and manifest?

Comment: have you tried it with a virtuell device too? If it works on other devices, than it must be an issue from the manufacturer.....

Comment: Have you done a complete uninstall, rebooted and reinstalled? If the app was previously installed targetting 22 or lower, permissions will be granted automatically to prevent user disruption.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley - Yes I did uninstalled, rebooted and reinstalled - But it behaved same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason. When My SMS app is installed which has requested SMS, PHONE, CONTACTS dangerous permissions, those are not granted ( after install, I verified in app manager ). Now I open the app and first screen asks users to make the App Default SMS App. When user makes it default sms app, Android Auto allows SMS, PHONE & CONTACTS permissions. Remaining permissions stay not-granted for run time.

Thanks everyone for your thoughts.